# Effect on all buttons in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to have a effect on all my buttons, but I can't seem to get the configuration right.

this is what I have now:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" >
        <Grid RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
                <ContentPresenter.Effects>
                    <effects:ShadowEffect Radius="5" DistanceX="5" DistanceY="5">
                        <effects:ShadowEffect.Color>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Black" />
                                <On Platform="Android" Value="White" />
                                <On Platform="UWP" Value="Red" />
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </effects:ShadowEffect.Color>
                    </effects:ShadowEffect>
                </ContentPresenter.Effects>
            </ContentPresenter>

        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But this throws a `Can't resolve ControlTemplateProperty on Button`.

Anybody has any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at [Xamarin.Forms Guides](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/introduction/#Creating_a_ControlTemplate) the Control Templates isn't applicable to Button.

> A ControlTemplate can be applied to the following types by setting
>   their ControlTemplate properties:
>
> - ContentPage
> - ContentView
> - TemplatedPage
> - TemplatedView

The error `Can't resolve ControlTemplateProperty on Button` make sense. `Button` inherites from `View`, not `TemplatedView` as would be needed.

So about your main point, effects cann't consumed directly by style, but you can achieve this thru attached properties. Here is some good references to you:

- [How to create an effect](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/creating/)
- [How to consume it with styles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/passing-parameters/attached-properties/#Consuming_the_Effect_with_a_Style)
- [A good example](http://xfcomplete.net/general/2016/01/20/using-effects/)

I hope it help you (and sorry for my bad english)