# Xamarin ControlTemplate Trigger applied to inner control within template

Tags: xamarin, triggers, controltemplate

[Coming from my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131444/xamarin-fail-on-derived-control-and-custom-style-content-template), I was trying to create a custom control and build a control template for it much like in WPF, but it failed on triggers.  I was provided a link that indicated that Control Templates are not allowed on all controls, but only certain ones via [another Stack Overflow link provided by Raimo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340655/effect-on-all-buttons-in-xamarin-forms/48346599#48346599) on my other question.

So now on to part 2.  I have changed the control from an "Entry" type to a "ContentView" type so a control template can be applied.  So that was the only thing changed

```csharp
namespace MyAndroidApp
{
    public class MyTextboxEntry : ContentView
    {
        public MyTextboxEntry()
        {}

        public static readonly BindableProperty IsRequiredProperty
            = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsRequired), typeof(bool),
                typeof(MyTextboxEntry), false, BindingMode.TwoWay);
        public bool IsRequired
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsRequiredProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsRequiredProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Namespace references..

```
xmlns:myCtrls="clr-namespace:MyAndroidApp"
```

Now, on to the control template.   I am actually defining multiple parts in the control but have abbreviated here for simple context.

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CT_MyTextboxEntry" >
    <!-- Having a grid as an outer wrapper for multiple internal controls... -->
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" x:Name="UpdateThisGridControl" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Entry Text="Sample" Grid.Column="0"  />
        <Label Text="junk" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Image Source="Sample.jpg" Grid.Column="2" />

    <Grid.Triggers>
        <Trigger TargetType="myCtrls:MyTextboxEntry" Property="IsRequired" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>

    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And the final instance of the control in the page to be displayed via

```xml
<myCtrls:MyTextboxEntry ControlTemplate="{StaticResource CT_MyTextboxEntry}" />
```

So, my failure is within the Grid.Triggers section.  The intent here is to use the bindable property of the new entry control (based on ContentView) with proper BindableProperty declaration for "IsRequired", but to set the background color of the GRID.

In WPF, you can say use the trigger from this thing here, but update this other control within the control template as referenced by an "x:Name" reference which I have in-place as "UpdateThisGridControl".

If I disable the [Grid.Triggers] part, the control and template show as expected.  As soon as I enable the trigger, it fails with

> "bindable" not an instance of AssociatedType

But, if you take into consideration that an entry ContentView has a background color property and so too does the Grid control, why is it choking when trying to set via trigger.

How can I do this type of binding for the property from the custom control to update a property within the specific control template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used `Grid.Triggers`, you should set the `TargetType="Grid"` in the `Trigger` Tab like following code.

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CT_MyTextboxEntry" >

   <!-- Having a grid as an outer wrapper for multiple internal controls... -->
   <Grid HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" x:Name="UpdateThisGridControl" IsEnabled="True" >
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="150*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <Entry Text="Sample" Grid.Column="0"  />
       <Label Text="junk" Grid.Column="1" />
       <Image Source="Sample.jpg" Grid.Column="2" />

       <!-- For testing, I set the value of `Property` is `IsEnabled`, it worked as normal -->
       <Grid.Triggers>
           <Trigger TargetType="Grid" Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
           </Trigger>
       </Grid.Triggers>
   </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But you want to set the `TargetType="myCtrls:MyTextboxEntry"` for `Trigger`, you can try to use **Style** to achieve it for `myCtrls:MyTextboxEntry`.

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
       <Style TargetType="myCtrls:MyTextboxEntry">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger TargetType="myCtrls:MyTextboxEntry"
                     Property="IsRequired" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />

                    <!-- Multiple setters elements are allowed -->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CT_MyTextboxEntry" >
        <!-- Having a grid as an outer wrapper for multiple internal controls... -->
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" x:Name="UpdateThisGridControl"  >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Entry Text="Sample" Grid.Column="0"  />
        <Label Text="junk" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Image Source="Sample.jpg" Grid.Column="2" />

            <!-- <Grid.Triggers>
                <Trigger TargetType="Grid" Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Grid.Triggers> -->

        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>

    <myCtrls:MyTextboxEntry ControlTemplate="{StaticResource CT_MyTextboxEntry}" IsRequired="True" />

</StackLayout>
```

Here is a running screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You partially misunderstood the question...  My custom control has a bindable property "IsREQUIRED" (not just enabled, but REQUIRED).  So that is the property of the outer control, not the grid within the control template.  I am trying to have the overall control "IsRequired" trigger the background color within the control template.

Comment: If you set the TargetType="myCtrls:MyTextboxEntry"  in ControlTemplate.  When you run your project, ControlTemplate was loaded first(myCtrls:MyTextboxEntry was not loaded at that time), Forms cannot found the `myCtrls:MyTextboxEntry`.  So If you disable the [Grid.Triggers] part, the control and template show as expected.  You can try to set the Style for `myCtrls:MyTextboxEntry` like my above answer, it will worked for all of the `myCtrls:MyTextboxEntry` controls.